Combined use of RGBD and LiDAR for SLAM
I am implementing SLAM on a robot with two LiDAR sensors on a ROS noetic system. These sensors are at a height where they cannot see objects on legs correctly (e.g., tables, production systems, etc.) which causes the robot to drive into things often. For that purpose I have installed two Intel Realsense D435 cameras on the robot, to give it pointcloud data, to see these types of objects.
I am having difficulties finding a method that lets me build a map using this method, that 'prioritizes' the cameras' scans. Most SLAM algorithms I've found only allow for one sensor type. I have attempted to use gmapping, but that overrides the scans found via cameras due to perceived raytracing from the LiDARs. I also tried using rtabmap_slam, but that seems incapable of using multiple cameras if they do not use the RGBDImage msg. Also, for some reason, it only uses the LiDARs if the subscribe_scan param is set to true.
I briefly considered only using the cameras with rtabmap_slam, but the grid_map ends up registering empty space under e.g., tables or similar.
